# Animated/3D show about a boy who travels to another dimension with two friends and meets a tiger or lion creature

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, isekai

I’m trying to find an animated/3D show made around 2009 to 2013 about a kid who is linked with a tiger or lion and that creature leads him to a another dimension, where he goes with his two friends, a boy and a girl, and they meet the creature there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[Invizimals](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4900224/)*** (2013).

From the [Invizimals Wiki](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Invizimals_(TV_Series)):

> What if I told you a scientist called Kenichi Nakamura had discovered invisible creatures living all around us? What if I told you he'd discovered a gate to travel from our world to theirs? And what if I told you we were embarking on a quest to unravel the mysteries of the Invizimals' world? Wanna join our team? Meet us after class. We are the Alliance of Invizimal Hunters, and we could really use your help.

It's 3D-animated, fits the timeframe, and involves three kids -- [Hiro](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Hiro), and his friends, [Sam](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Sam) and [Lima](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Lima) -- travelling to another world where they meet a creature named [Tigershark](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Tigershark).