# Fantasy kids' show involving three characters, one with a long blue hexagon gauntlet across forearm which turned them into different beasts

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I recall seeing this show about seven years or more ago on TV.

It had three main characters; one girl and two boys. One of the boys was an inventor, they had blonde hair, the other had dark brown hair and had this long gauntlet all the way up their arm.

This gauntlet (I believe) contained an orangish sort of crystal inside of it, and the pattern on the top of it along his arm was light-blue hexagons.
This gauntlet allowed the boy to turn into different beasts that he encountered, I think one of them was some kind of big panda (similar visually to the Pokemon Pangoro).

The main story may have included some sort of big company that wanted to possibly capture these beasts for their own use? And at some point may have persuaded the blonde-haired boy to betray the other two.

They were able to travel to different worlds (through portals?), which is where they found these beasts.

This show was likely a computer-generated animation.

This show isn't *Ben 10*.

At some point randomly in the show, I remember they find Terracotta warrior statues; not sure that helps though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this animated or live-action? If animated, was it hand-drawn or computer-generated? And what colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: (New Account) I think it was an animated show, most likely computer generated. I'm not sure of the main character's hair colour. I remember a big company being the main evil in the show at some point, and the other main boy in the trio was possibly some sort of inventor? It's been quite a while since I've seen the show. I do remember that one of the episodes at some point had some reference to terracotta warriors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated series about three kids and powered animals in a jungle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278411/animated-series-about-three-kids-and-powered-animals-in-a-jungle)

Comment: @LogicDictates That question does not have an accepted answer.  Until it do this is not considered a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Bjorn Eriksson - The answer to that question isn't marked as accepted, but the OP did confirm it to be correct via a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278411/animated-series-about-three-kids-and-powered-animals-in-a-jungle/278418#comment767990_278418) left directly beneath it, which is as good as an acceptance in relation to dupe closures. The question is already serving as the dupe target for a [previously closed duplicate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267237/122024).

Comment: I’d rather close in the opposite direction, keeping the q with the  accepted answer as the dupe target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[Invizimals](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4900224/)*** (2013).

The show revolves around three kids who are regularly sent through a portal to another world by a scientist to study mysterious creatures known as Invizimals.

The three kids in question are a brown-haired Japanese boy named [Hiro](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Hiro), a blond British boy (and self-professed inventor) named [Sam](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Sam), and a Brazilian girl named [Lima](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Lima). They each wear bracer-like devices with small blue hexagons on them on their left forearms.

> [image: Image of Hiro, Lima, Sam and Tigershark from "Invizimals."]

According to the [TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Invizimals), Hiro has the ability to duplicate the forms of Invizimals if he can obtain their crystals. An Invizimal named [Tigershark](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Tigershark) gives Hiro his crystal near the start of the second episode and tells him to use it if he's ever in peril.

> In the show, a secret scientific project recruits three kids to explore another dimension inhabited by creatures called "Invizimals." **One of the kids, Hiro, has the ability to duplicate the forms of Invizimals if he can obtain their crystals.** It turns out that the dimension is being invaded by mechanical beings called X-Tractors, so the kids end up helping the Invizimals defend their world.

Episode 11 is titled "[Terracotta Warriors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5196526/)" and involves a panda-like Invizimal named [Xiong Mao](https://invizipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Xiong_Mao) stealing hundreds of statues with the goal of bringing them to life.

> Hundreds of statues of the Terracotta Warriors have disappeared from a museum in London. The unit Z1 tracks them, and finds out that all has been a work of the invizimal Xiaong Mao, who plans to bring the warriors back to life and to use them against the XTractors.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds kinda like "Ben 10"? There are a few reboots of the show but I'll link the OG show's Wiki article. You'll find them all anyways if you just search up Ben 10.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10

If I'm right then the "Gauntlet" is called the Omnitrix, which is some alien watch that let's him turn into alien beasts like 'Four Arms', 'Alien X', 'Heatblast' or 'Diamond Head'.

The girl might be Gwen, his cousin, who in the first show is raised alongside Ben by their grandpa, Max. She has weird pink power blast powers. The other guy might be OG rival, Kevin Levin, who in the OG show hated Ben and was some bad boy with powers to absorb other things or powers. In the reboot where they're all older, they become friends.

The show overall follows Ben and Gwen, living in their Grandpa Max's RV, just tryna live life, but then a comet hits nearby their camp one night and Ben unwillingly gets bound by the Omnitrix. He then discovers its powers. Every episode then goes on as other weirdo alien bad guys attack, Kevin Levin shenanigans, and overarching plot that the main villain is the evil ctopus looking alien overlord, 'Vilgax'.

[image: Ben 10's omnitrix]

Here's the Omnitrix as it looked in the original show, it changes appearance slightly in the other versions but the green hourglass in black circle centre part stays the same. It's not exactly 'hexagons' but it does the same as your question's Gauntlet.

Comment: Could you include a picture of the Omnitrix to show how it matches the description in the question?

Comment: I've added it now :D

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not Ben 10 I'm talking about. The kid in the show I'm thinking of has a full gauntlet-like object on his forearm with a blue-coloured hexagon pattern. I did think that it sounded like Ben 10 when I wrote it, but I didn't clarify that it wasn't in the question.